# is WeblogicTransactionManagerLookup removed or deprecated in hibernate 4.x?

Tags: hibernate

i have spent the past 2 - 3 days making spring 4.x , hibernate 4.x work with weblogic + jta
One of the things I needed ( i think I need to ) configure is :

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.WeblogicTransactionManagerLookup</property>
```

I see this class in hibernate - hibernate-3.1.3.jar
I dont see this in hibernate  - hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar

Google does not tell me anything and all I get is references to 3.x version :
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/transaction/WeblogicTransactionManagerLookup.html

any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transaction manager lookup class property itself is deprecated in Hibernate 4.

https://mriet.wordpress.com/2012/09/21/jta-manager-lookup-as7-hibernate/

Comment: thanks Brad - but the frustrating thing is i went through java docs and till 3.6 I cans ee it and boom from 4.0 all they provide is 'TransactionManagerLookup' interface and not the implementation class - almost looks like hibernate is managed by a bunch of arrogant jokers - no mention in documentation of it being dropped - thanks for your help and inputs

Comment: Anytime.  Hibernate 4 lacks severely in documentation about actually running it standalone.  They assume that you're running in JBoss AS which sets all that up for you.